# Undefined reference with boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am trying to add a version to a template class like below

```cpp
namespace boost{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Base, class Derived>
        struct version<Cloneable<Base, Derived>>
        {
            BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(unsigned int, value = 5);
        };
    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

This gives an undefined reference like below

> ld.exe: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAZtGO4.o:foo.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN5boost13serialization7versionI9CloneableI4base3fooEE5valueE[.refptr._ZN5boost13serialization7versionI9CloneableI4base3fooEE5valueE]+0x0): **undefined reference to 'boost::serialization::version<Cloneable<base, foo> >::value**'

When compiling without any optimization like below

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 \
    base.cpp \
    foo.cpp \
    -I${BOOST_HOME}\include \
    -L${BOOST_HOME}\lib \
    -lboost_serialization-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_73 \
```

but when adding any optimization flags "-O1 or -Og ,...etc" it links properly!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you find any solution?